# Workaround or method to have an web application user provide a local filepath via a web application form?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I understand that allowing a web application to know a local file system path to an item or document is a security vulnerability, hence the protections that only provide the browser with the full name of the item being selected and not the path to the item on the user's local system.

I am wondering what methods others are using to have a user provide their local filepath easily, without having to copy and paste from the file explorer.

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC project, where our users will be submitting a local filepath to a file on the shared drive here at the office, but there must be some easier way of letting the user specify their particular path.  Am open to any recommendations, libraries, etc.

EDIT:
Mozilla docs for the FileReader API state:
"FileReader can only access the contents of files that the user has explicitly selected, either using an HTML  element or by drag and drop. It cannot be used to read a file by pathname from the user's file system. To read files on the client's file system by pathname, use the File System Access API. To read server-side files, use standard Ajax solutions, with CORS permission if reading cross-domain."

File system access API seems to have the same restrictions as FileReader.

I am aware of this, I am looking for some other alternative that are easier than making the user copy and paste the string from their file explorer path.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get full path of selected file on change of <input type=‘file’> using javascript, jquery-ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15201071/how-to-get-full-path-of-selected-file-on-change-of-input-type-file-using-jav)